# How to display list view of a Sonata admin in a dashbord block

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata, symfony-3.3

I'd like to have a list (or more lists) directly available on dashboard.

Since data grids and actions I want to use are already configured in respective Admin classes, is there a simple way to reuse that via a Dashboard block?

Comment: What does it mean "to reuse via Dashboard"? From out of the box you have all your admin classes with list and create buttons per each of them in Dashboard block. Can you explain if the dashboard block has already viewed in your admin?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Layke sadly, no